# What are steps to start a Soap Listener in Websphere MQ server given a WSDL

Tags: soap, ibm-mq

I have a Websphere MQ server 7.5 deployed and sanity validated (basic put and get). I would like to start a SOAP listener on this MQ server set up, given that I have a WSDL in hand.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. MQ won't do anything with your WSDL. What do you want to do with the SOAP messages? Are you using SOAP over MQ?

Comment: Pardon my newbeeness in the domain. I am trying to run a sample from the IBM documentation http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032960_.htm Yes the idea is to use SOAP over MQ. Starting with a POJO I have created a WSDL for it. And next step I would like to start a SOAP listener using this WSDL. Eventually would like to generate a client side code using the same WSDL and do some validation posts to the SOAP listener. Was looking for a good tutorial link which describes the steps involved to be able to do this. Thanks